# Is there a way to see how many questions I have answered or asked by tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, personal-statistics

I was curious about my activity on SO by tag, something like this:

SQL Server   10 Questions / 99 Answers
C#           5 Questions / 70 Answers.

If it doesn't already exist, it would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is already available, on the tags section of your user page. Hover over the number to the left of the tag, and you will see how many you have answered and asked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you find the data-dump thread, several people have put this data together...it's not absolutely current, but it is interesting!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox

Comment: That's the one! I have nothing but trouble with the search here :)